# What is the difference in interpretation of the "probability" returned by a kNN or a DNN algorithm

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, scikit-learn, knn

I have two datasets, each defined by the same two parameters. If you plot them on a scatter plot, there is some overlap. I'd like to classify them, but also get a probability that a given point is in one dataset or another. So in the overlap region, I would never expect the probability to be 100%.

I've implemented this using python's scikit-learn package and the kNN algorithm, KNeighborsClassifier. It looks pretty good! When I use [`predict_proba`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html#sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.predict_proba) to return the probability, it looks like what I would expect!

So then I tried doing the same thing with TensorFlow and the DNNClassifier classifier, mostly as a learning exercise for myself. When I evaluate the test samples I used `predict_proba` to return the probabilities, but the distribution of probabilities look much different than the kNN approach. It looks like the DNNClassifier is really trying to drive the probabilities to 1 or 0, rather than somewhere in between for the overlapping region.

I've not posted code here because my questions is more basic: can I interpret the probabilities returned by these two approaches in the same way? Or is there a fundamental difference between them?

Thanks!

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to aim at. If both your classifiers are guessing the same thing (classes/labels) and the returned probabilities are defined in the same way (prob per class, or one-versus all; read the docs) they are comparable. "Driving the prob to 0 or 1"... are you saying DNN is just doing a better job at classification, seen in a lower logloss?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Provided you used sigmoid or softmax for prediction you should be getting values that are reasonable to interpret as probabilities (DNNClassifier will use softmax as far as I know).

Now you didn't give us any details on the models. Depending on the complexity of the models and the training parameters you might be getting more over fitting.

If you are seeing extreme (0 or 1) values for the overlapping area it's probably over fitting. Use test/validation set to keep a check on it.

From what you are describing a very simple model should do, try to have less depth, less parameters.

Comment: Thanks for this. I did use a validation set, but I should check the number of parameters and the depth. Will post back here after I do this!